# Rails and Devise: How to redirect user back to the requested Page after successful login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, devise

I am using the idiom described in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/action_controller_overview.html#other-ways-to-use-filters

```
# /app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter do |controller|
    redirect_to new_login_url unless controller.send(:logged_in?)
  end
end
```

Now if the signing in process is successful, how

1. can I examine if it was, and b)
2. how can I re-redirect the user to the requested controller action?
3. How do I do this login-process via AJAX and JSON ?

EDIT: Also I get the following Error Message

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::LoginFilter
```

When I use the more elaborate solution suggested in `6.2 Other Ways to Use Filters` instead of the one above such that my Controller looks like this

```
# /app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_return_path, LoginFilter

  def set_return_path
    return if devise_controller?
    session['user_return_to'] = request.url unless current_user
  end

  class LoginFilter

    def self.filter(controller)
      unless controller.send(:logged_in?)
      controller.flash[:error] = "You must be logged in"
      controller.redirect_to controller.new_login_url
    end

   end
  end   
end
```

Thanks

von Spotz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `before_action` in the `application_controller.rb` where you save the requested page url:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_return_path

  def set_return_path
    return if devise_controller?

    session['user_return_to'] = request.url unless current_user
  end
end
```

And then redirect the user to this url after the successful sign-in:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return root_url if session['user_return_to'].blank?

    session['user_return_to']
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! "2 more to go"

Comment: @vonspotz You can check the `current_user` variable in your controller and if it is set that means the user is logged in. And if it is `nil`, the user is not logged in.

Comment: Please Sachin, tell me, where is this SessionController? Obviously the tutorials I read didn't cover that. Best wishes !

Comment: Is SessionsController a replacement for the UsersController?

Comment: @vonspotz SessionsController is a `devise` gem's controller and here you need to override the `after_sign_in_path_for` method definition. And it can be done exactly the way I have defined the controller in the sample.

Comment: Where do I put it, please? Thanks Sachin Singh

Comment: you need to create a `sessions_controller.rb` file inside `app/controllers` and add this logic there.

Comment: Also, add this in the routes:
`devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'sessions'
}`

Comment: Hello Sachin, I have read that in a tutorial. But the routes entry seems like SessionsController is a replacement for UsersController. Is that correct or wrong? I think I will make an own thread... Maybe it's just a namespace ...

Comment: it's just for adding any custom logic around devise's sessions_controller-
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Comment: My app folder doesn't have this controller. I got the feeling i missed out on some devise generator command or something.

Comment: I forgot to issue the command `$ rails generate devise:controllers users`. The following blog post made me aware of it https://henrytabima.github.io/rails-setup/docs/devise/configuring-controllers Thanks to the author of the blog post and to you Sachin Singh

Comment: But now I find it auto-generated `Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` due to the scope. What difference does it make? Cheers.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference. You can name your controller anything. Just make sure it is extending devise's controller.